# Android - Why I'm unable to add hyphen to CharSequence - Java

Tags: java, android

Well the next thing could be look a bit silly, but I hope someone will be kind enough to help me.

What I'm trying to do is the next thing - a String value, then hyphen, and after it the time in milliseconds - Just like that -

```
name-13456789
```

I've tried this code -

```
String saveUser = "user";
String timeOfMAking = String.valueOf(time);
CharSequence Title = saveUser +"-"+ timeOfMAking;
```

But the result is as follows -

```
user13456789
```

So what am I doing wrong here?
Does anyone know how to solve it?
And a simple explanation of why I'm getting this result would be nice, thanks.

Comment: Try using stringbuilder inside it u will find append method try and let me know whether it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it like that:

```
String saveUser = "user";
String timeOfMAking = String.valueOf(time);
String title = saveUser +"-"+ timeOfMAking;
```

Use `String` instead of `CharSequence`.

Btw, for me your code is working:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me, CharSequence or String anyway. I prefer this way though :

```
  String saveUser = "user";
  String timeOfMAking = String.valueOf(1000000000);
  String result = saveUser.concat("-".concat(timeOfMAking));
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume time is a long that is returned from new Date().getTime(); yes?
Also, please camel case the CharSequence declaration! (CharSequence title, not CharSequence Title)

Your code works if it looks like this:

```
long time = new Date().getTime();
String saveUser = "user";
String timeOfMAking = String.valueOf(time);
CharSequence title = saveUser +"-"+ timeOfMAking;
System.out.println(title);
```

or:

```
String saveUser = "user";
String timeOfMAking = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
CharSequence title = saveUser +"-"+ timeOfMAking;
System.out.println(title);
```

Also, I noticed that I don't see in your sample code a print statement, so how many lines of code are there in between your

```
CharSequence Title = saveUser +"-"+ timeOfMAking;
```

And the "result" as you put it?  As a follow up question to that, is there any code after what you've posted here that manipulates CharSequence further?

Answer (score -2):

Use an escape character

```
                String saveUser = "user";
            String timeOfMAking = String.valueOf(time);
            CharSequence Title = saveUser +" \- "+ timeOfMAking;
```

Comment: Umm, you don't have to escape hyphens in strings.